# I have been creating new Git branches from older branch without checking out to the master

Tags: git, git-commit, branching-and-merging, git-merge-conflict

I have been checking out to new branches from the older branch, instead of checking out to the master. 
currently, I have created four new features: home_feature, admin_user-feature, customer_request, blog_feature.

I forgot to checkout to the master before creating the "customer_request" branch, and create the feature by moving into the blog feature.
now I am faced with a lot of conflicts. I have tried using 'git rebase' but the commits are up to 80 commits per branch, so it not practical.
How can I resolve these conflicts?

[image]

Comment: What I tend to do is to create a new feature branch off master, then list the commit hashes in the existing feature branch, in chronological order, in a text editor. Then take the first one and try to cherry pick it in your new (master copy) branch. If there is a conflict then you know that you amended files/folders that are not in master in the same state, and a manual conflict resolution may be in order.

Comment: I have been stuck on this issue for the past 2 days. Thanks this worked for me, cherrypicking from the first commit to the last relevant commit of the older branch to a new feature of the master reduce the conflicts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the comments, this appeared to be the solution. You had three branches:

- Master (M)
- Old feature branch (O)
- New feature branch (N)

N was branched off O accidentally, rather than M, which is what you intended. This means that there is a series of commits starting at a certain point in time in N and you want to recreate the branch with those commits as if you had branched from M.

The solution was to create a new branch:

- Newer feature branch (N2 from M)

Then identify a series of commit hashes from N, and apply them to N2. You can do that manually by cherry-picking each one in turn.

There was a risk that these would not apply cleanly, because M might have changed some files compared to O, and thus your work in N would have been based on outdated files/folders. Text change merging is a fairly simple algorithm, it does not understand code structure like humans can (in other words, not everything is mergeable).

However, as it turned out, the cherry-picks applied cleanly. If you had not been able to do that, you might have had to create a diff for each failing one, and see how to apply it manually to N2 given the changes in M. Where this happens, it is worth still trying to cherry-pick following commits, as they might not all need manual conflict resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You could either do a merge and fix the conflicts only once instead of perhaps multiple times as you might have to do with a rebase.

Or you could let Git automatically pick either your changes or master's changes when there are conflicts.

For example, if you do a rebase, you could add the [`ours`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt-ours) (or `theirs`) option to the recursive merge strategy.

For example, the following command would rebase your branch on top of master and for any conflicts, it will choose **your** changes instead of the changes from master:

```
git rebase master -Xtheirs
```

The `theirs` and `ours` is a bit counter-intuitive in this case. `-Xtheirs` will choose your changes and `-Xours` will pick the changes from master.

Comment: thank for your help.... but I think creating a new branch from the master and cherrypick the necessary commit was more effective.

Comment: Sounds like the same thing as a rebase.